# If $a,b$ are natural numbers that $a>b,gcd(a+b,ab-1)=1,gcd(a-b,ab+1)=1$ then prove that $(ab+1)^2+(a-b)^2$ can be a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

If $a,b$ are natural numbers that $a>b,gcd(a+b,ab-1)=1,gcd(a-b,ab+1)=1$ then prove that $(ab+1)^2+(a-b)^2$ can be a perfect square.

**My attempt**:

$(ab+1)^2+(a-b)^2=(ab)^2+a^2+b^2+1=(a^2+1)(b^2+1)=x^2$

But I am stuck in that point.

Comment: It is Iran second round MO https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h347464p1862069

Comment: the question should be "cannot be a perfect square"